# Are their any alternative for UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios

As UDID has been deprecated are their any alternative ways for UDID?

Comment: for what purpose are you using

Comment: As you type in a question, SO offers you a list of possible related questions. Please review those before posting your question. This avoids duplicates.

Comment: Here's a lib might helps: https://github.com/Kjuly/UIApplication-UIID

Comment: If it is declared a duplicate, then the duplicate has to be cross-referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following thing as a unique Identifier for your app user's :

I use the method below to create a UUID and save it to the user preferences the first time the app is started:

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniqueID"];
    if (!UUID)
    {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];
    }
    return UUID;
}
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

Apple stopped supporting a unique identifier for iOS. This source code solves the problem. It generates a unique identifier based on the mac address of the device in combination with the bundle identifier.

Please download the demo http://bit.ly/10SXhrO